# How to convert String to double with point?

Tags: xcode, string, double, coordinate

I'm currently working on an app that works with locations and therefore I have the following code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2d coord;
coord.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
coord.latitide = [latitude doubleValue];
```

Seems legit, doesn't it?
Now longitude and latitude are STRINGS like "10.112233". I know that normally double hasn't got points in there, but the cllocationcoordinate2d wants it like that...

Now, if you NSLog the strings, they work just fine, but if you NSLog the doubleValues it simply return nothing. **How can I fix that?**

Comment: Ensure you're using the correct print formatter for a double, %f

Comment: That's strange. Can you show more code to include the logging? Also as an aside, doubles normally have decimal points in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
NSString *coordinateAsString = @"10.112233";
coord.longitude = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:coordinateAsString] doubleValue];
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me now. i also got another mistake before that, which caused the nils, but this one helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `NSDecimalNumber` like following:

```
NSString *string = @"10.112233";
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string];
```

Comment: Nah, doesn't work "sending incompatible type NSDecimalNumber to instance of type CLLocationDegrees (aka double)"